# Is QueryDocumentSnapshot listening for the number of time we use it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application using Firebase(Firestore) and Flutter.

So Firebase is charging us for every request after reaching 20 000 requests.
At every call to Firestore, we get a List of QueryDocumentSnapshot containing our data.

***I wonder if a QueryDocumentSnapshot can act as a tracker counting each consultation to a document.***

Before building this app I have built another application using the same tools.
But I was extracting every data of Query Snapshot Documents in a classic List of Maps, the result is ~200 reads per day developing (being the only one using the app).

For my new application, I am directly using Query Document Snapshot to host data but it seems that firebase counts me a lot of reads ~1000 per day developing (being the only one using the app).

***So, is Query Document Snapshot of Firebase acts like a tracker in addition to classic HTTP requests/responses gets.***

*NB: QueryDocumentSnapshot is a class defined in the cloud_firebase prototypes file.*

Answer (score 1):

Firebase charges only for the number of time you req for documents. You might be requesting only 100 reads but it may be possible that you might be hot reloading or hot restarting your app to check your code and that's why more requests for read and hence more no of reads. And for clear details check their documents.